# simple slidtoggle function with multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four different divs with slideToggle function. I set them to slidetoggle on click, and they work fine. However, I want the rest of the divs to close when one div is clicked. can anyone help?
below is the code I have so far.

```
<div id="01"><p>title</p></div>
    <div id="01_sub"><p>content</p></div>
<div id="02"><p>title</p></div>
    <div id="02_sub"><p>content</p></div>
<div id="03"><p>title</p></div>
    <div id="03_sub"><p>content</p></div>
<div id="04"><p>title</p></div>
    <div id="04_sub"><p>content</p></div>


$('#01_sub').hide();
      $('#01').click(function() {
       $('#01_sub').slideToggle('medium');
     });
     $('#02_sub').hide();
      $('#02').click(function() {
       $('#02_sub').slideToggle('medium');
     });
     $('#03_sub').hide();
      $('#03').click(function() {
       $('#03_sub').slideToggle('medium');
     });
     $('#04_sub').hide();
      $('#04').click(function() {
       $('#04_sub').slideToggle('medium');
     });
```

so basically, if I click #01, I want #02,#03,#04 to stay closed or to be closed. and if I click #02, I want the rest to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="01" class="toggle"><p>title</p></div>
<div id="01_sub"><p>content</p></div>
<div id="02" class="toggle"><p>title</p></div>
<div id="02_sub"><p>content</p></div>
<div id="03" class="toggle"><p>title</p></div>
<div id="03_sub"><p>content</p></div>
<div id="04" class="toggle"><p>title</p></div>
<div id="04_sub"><p>content</p></div>
```

then

```
var $toggles = $('.toggle'), $subs = $toggles.next().hide();
$toggles.click(function(){
    var $next = $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideToggle('medium');
    $subs.not($next).slideUp();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gTVwu/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/WbYu9/2/

```
$('.title').click(function(){
    $('.showed').removeClass('showed');
    $(this).addClass('showed');
    $("div[id*='sub']").slideUp();
    if($(this).hasClass('showed')){    
     $("div[id='"+$(this).attr('id')+"_sub']").slideDown();
    }
})
```

this is more elastic form.